# Offered job overseas, but employer reluctant to offer any sort of relocation package

Tags: new-job, relocation

I'm in the UK and have been offered a position with a software developer (currently a one-man-band) in Norway.  I have known the chap for a few years, and he has a successful product in Norway and earns a good living from it, the business has a lot of (Norwegian) customers.  He did until recently have a developer working alongside him, who recently left to pursue other activities.

As a result of his previous developer leaving, he has now asked me to come on board to take over some of the development work to give him an opportunity to go out and sell to customers.  Initially this will be me working from home remotely, however ultimately he has asked me to relocate to Norway and join him in the office, although this is a few months away.  Once based out of the office we would then work on further expanding the reach of the product and work to launch the product in the global market.

We have agreed a deal in principle with a good salary which would be linked to company performance (any new customers will increase my salary past a certain point and I would also gain equity in the company).

Am I being unreasonable to expect or want a relocation package as part of this job offer?  Would it be fair for me to ask for one?

Comment: What's reasonable may be hard to determine, but you are basically asking him to personally pay for you to relocate.

Comment: The reverse is also true, where OP would be personally paying to relocate. The size of an employer has no bearing on whether a request is reasonable or not.

Comment: Have you considered asking for practical assistance rather than money? For example, finding an apartment could require either travel to Norway or staying in a hotel for the first week or so,  both expensive. You could save that money if your employer found somewhere for you to live.

Comment: The simple unfortunate answer here is **completely forget about it** :/  if they don't have 10 grand for you to move, it's going nowhere.  I mean what's next, they can't afford a couple grand for PCs?

Comment: OF COURSE you would have to get full relocation - it's basically "one month's salary" - to move to Norway (for goodness sake!)  It is inconceivable that you would pay this yoruself, Adzzz.  Why?  You can get a job in the UK at the drop of a hat.  However, the "elephant in the room" here is, for what possible reason would the person not want you working remotely?  Do that.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Thank you. yes this is one of the things I was considering.  I was over there last weekend (with my partner) and we were discussing many things and accommodation was one of them.  If he could find a property for us to rent and help with the initial deposit, this would go some way to helping with the other relocation costs.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks, I was not aware as to how much the relocation packages usually are.  One months salary up front would certainly help.  And as to working remotely - well, for time being I am (part time), but he wants me to be based "in country" eventually, which I'm absolutely happy to do.  As long as the terms are fair to both of us.

Comment: hey @AdzzzUK, purely FWIW, one man's opinion - and only based on my minimal knowledge of the situation.  I'd say the guy's mention of "relocation" is in the "utterly ridiculous" category.  "Is he dreaming?" -type of thing.  It's the sort of mention or suggestion I just wouldn't even respond to, just take it is a passing somewhat bizarre comment.  Sure, once the money's coming in in container ships, you're being paid the most senior, highest rates in the field, and you own a large percentage of equity, he can (pay a lot) to move you and your family there. It's a non-starter, I'd say!

Comment: A worthwhile tip when companies/individuals make relocation suggestions, is, simply deflect it by **putting it off**.  Simply reply (if you reply at all), with a two words like "we could consider that in the new year" " .. the new school year" "after version X launches" "something to think about when my lease expires" ... and so on.  (Don't "go in to it too much" because it's fundamentally a totally silly idea to "relocate"! for anything other than the most high-paying, high-flying product.)  Getting back to your specific question, once again, **YES, OF COURSE, OBVIOUSLY** they'd ..

Comment: ... they'd have to pay every single penny of the move in question, obviously.

Comment: Hey @Fattie - I did initially have some scepticism but the offer is firmly on the table.  I would be replacing the other dev who left, remember.   I've been freelancing for him for a number of years, have built a good working relationship with him, and have been over to Norway a few times already for a few different reasons.  This is a genuine position and includes equity which would increase over time, and a strong position within the company as it expands out of Norway into Europe and beyond.

Comment: ...but yes I will definitely take your comments on board.  Thanks!

Comment: HI @AdzzzUK, all i can say is, on the "who pays" front, it's just totally inconceivable YOU would pay any of the moving expenses.  It would be "unheard of and bizarre" you know?  Some language to use there would be along the lines "Don't forget moving my family will be quite expensive for the company, surely 15,000 pounds or more, do you want to deal with that in a lump sum or cover the invoices or?"

Comment: Regarding the shares etc, I would just remind that, in every case ever of a startup in software or early stage company, for 30 years now, the company offers or gives "some shares" with a job.  **By all means** you may be on to a winner and in two years you'll be rich - and that's great, but as every programmer knows "be careful"!

Comment: Other excellent language to use here:  *"Sounds great. You seem to be saying that the company wouldn't be able to afford the 10 thousand or so to do this at the moment.  Of course, I certainly couldn't afford that in any way presently!  Let's review the situation in the new year..."*

Comment: It should be added that you can't just up and move to Norway, anyway: You need a [personnummer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Norway) in order to do absolutely **anything** in the country (get paid, open a bank account, get an apartment, register a car, get a bus subscription) so you basically need to either get that arranged before arriving (which can take quite a while) or have enough money to survive in one of the most expensive countries in the world with no pay for several months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need help with the relocation expenses to move to Norway, then you need help with the relocation expenses to move to Norway. You don't have to accept an offer, no matter how good it is otherwise, if it doesn't give you what you need. It is also OK to tell your prospective employer what you need to get you to join. He's trying to hire you; it is OK for you to set the terms it will take to make that happen. Working for a start-up is risky to begin with, and asking you to uproot your life to move to a different country while taking on that risk is a big ask. It is not unreasonable for you to ask for something to compensate for that.

Since you describe it as a one-man startup, it is entirely possible that he doesn't have the money to give you relocation expense, and you should be prepared for that. He may not have the cash for it. But that isn't your problem. He needs to make it worth your while to go work for him. If he can't give you relocation expenses, see if he will offer something else like more pay or equity or some other bonus. Or maybe you can keep working remotely and delay the move. Whatever it is you need to make you want to work for him.

Employment should be a mutually-beneficial arrangement. You both need to get something out of it (he needs your skills in Norway, you need help getting to Norway). If you aren't, then it isn't a good relationship, and it is OK to respectfully turn him down.

Comment: I appreciate everyones' input, but am accepting this as the answer because you've nailed it.  There needs to be a bit of flexibility on both sides.  It's good to know my thoughts aren't completely unreasonable, I am after all willing to negotiate terms and this is a few months off, however it should definitely be a topic of discussion so we can reach some sort of agreement.  Thank you, Seth.

Answer (score 12):

It's not unreasonable for you to ask, or an unreasonable thing to expect. However most startups have a really huge problem with cashflow. The thing that kills them is not bad sales or poor profitability, but simply running out of money.

If this guy gave you moving expenses, those would have to be paid you now, and that comes out of cashflow. The company might literally not have that money, and even if it does it might bring forward the date he has to go looking for more funding, distracting from his sales efforts, and if he can't find it, killing the company. If, on the other hand, you were able to fund your own move, and take a higher salary or more equity in the company, that might keep the company alive longer.

You are of course entitled to ask for relocation, and to refuse to move if you don't get it, but be aware that the developer may not be in a position to offer a big cash payment right now.

Comment: DJ, your numbers see, to be off here.  (Like, way off.)  We're not talking about buying a jet.  Quite simply, relocation is **about the same as one month's salary**.  And that's that.  if they can't just toss around **one month's salary** here and there, they quite simply **will have trouble paying his salary** the next time it's due in, let's see, 6 days if it's the 16th of the month.

Comment: I've seen moves that cost several months salary, and I've certainly seen startups where a few months salary makes a difference. It might be worth the OP telling prospective employer what sort of sum he is talking about.

Comment: I guess that's conceivable DJ ... fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

It's not unreasonable at all. If he wants you, he has to compete with all the potential employers in the UK, where relocation wouldn't be needed. On the other hand, you compete with all the potential employees in Norway where relocation isn't needed.

You should know what you need to charge, and that includes relocation. If that is too expensive for the employer, so be it. In that case you will have to find a job elsewhere.

Comment: Keep in mind though that he does get a deal that is presumably better and more tailored to him than any potential UK employer though. So all in all yes in normal situations a relocation package should be due, given though the nature of the company(startup) and the potentially increased benefits & salary promised to the OP, its up to him to decide if thats a deal breaker or not.

Answer (score -7):

Just to officially put in an answer to the question per se,

> Would it be fair for me to ask for one?

It would be totally inconceivable that you would pay your own moving expenses.

(Don't even *ask* "if" they are going to pay, just start talking about the mechanics of how the move is going to happen.  You would no more ask "if" they are going to pay your moving expenses, than, you would ask "if" they are going to pay your salary that month.)

A typical relocation budget is **two month's salary** (certainly not less than one). Often, to try to cut corners and save money, employers will simply offer you a fixed amount of cash ("we'll give you two months salary *"towards"* relocation"); it's your choice whether you'd rather do that or have them "pay the invoices".

The facts of the situation would seem to be

- the previous programmer left the company. they would not have done that if from their inside position they knew they were about to finally "make it big". it's a huge red flag.
- almost all of startups "offer equity". it's as valuable/unique as getting free coffee.
- almost all startups in this position evaporate. in this case the OP would be left stuck in a foreign country. at that future time, when the OP asks "so can you give me money to get back home so I can work again" the answer will be "oh, we went bankrupt. Bummer. Nice weather right?" You can't get blood from a stone.
- there is zero reason for the OP to be on site, it's a whacky "offhand" idea of the company in question
- in today's market OP can trivially get a job and/or contract work, remote if preferred, anywhere, including OP's home region
- you *might* take a risk and pay your own moving expenses to go work for a large, hot company (indeed: large hot companies often demand that, they know they're in a position to say "we don't pay relocation"), it's unheard of to pay your own moving expenses to take a risk on one of zillions of startups. no more than you would, say, "buy them office furniture to help out"
- relocation costs nothing compared to other endless ongoing costs, not to mention salary costs. If company literally "can't afford it this month" the company is a non-starter. It would literally be in the ballpark of saying "oh we need three laptops just now - but we can't afford them"

Solution: just minimizes the "relocation" idea, with language such as "let's consider that in the new year".

Comment: Utterly, totally, fully inconceivable. What planet is everyone on here? Indeed the fact that it's a one-man startup makes it inconceivable.  What possible reason would someone risk 10,000 euros moving, for a one-man startup? *Maybe* you'd (for some reason - why?) pay 10,000 of your own money to take a bet on Google still being in business in two years.

Comment: Maybe "unimaginable" is closer :)  For anyone who has "been on Mars" I typed in a few reasons why this is not sensible or coherent, in today's market.

Comment: I respect your opinion of course @JoeStrazzere, but opinions seem to differ on this!

Comment: "100% of startups offer equity", "99.9% of startups in this position evaporate" - You are making some pretty strong assertions here with no data to support your opinion.